# Extract a part of UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, resize, warp

I was wondering if it's possible to "extract" a part of `UIImageView`.

For example, I select using Warp Affine a part of the `UIImageView` and I know the selected part `frame`.

like in this image:

[image]

Is it possible to get from the original `UIImageView` only the selected part without losing quality?

Comment: how did you do this selection area? =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the snapshot of the view via category method:

```
@implementation UIView(Snapshot)

-(UIImage*)makeSnapshot
{
  CGRect wholeRect = self.bounds;

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(wholeRect.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  [[UIColor blackColor] set];
  CGContextFillRect(ctx, wholeRect);
  [self.layer renderInContext:ctx];

  UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return image;
}

@end
```

then crop it to your rect via another category method:

```
@implementation UIImage(Crop)

-(UIImage*)cropFromRect:(CGRect)fromRect
{
  fromRect = CGRectMake(fromRect.origin.x * self.scale,
                        fromRect.origin.y * self.scale,
                        fromRect.size.width * self.scale,
                        fromRect.size.height * self.scale);
  CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, fromRect);
  UIImage* crop = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];
  CGImageRelease(imageRef);
  return crop;
}

@end
```

in your VC:

```
UIImage* snapshot = [self.imageView makeSnapshot];
UIImage* imageYouNeed = [snapshot cropFromRect:selectedRect];
```

`selectedRect` should be in you `self.imageView` coordinate system, if no so then use
`selectedRect = [self.imageView convertRect:selectedRect fromView:...]`

Comment: I'm sorry but your image cropping method is not working good. It seems to return a random part of the image, not the selected one. I'm currently using this method: http://pastie.org/private/wxmefesfdsu30vxf8un7q It seems to work pretty good, but it's a bit inaccurate, maybe you could help me fixing it ? For example, if I make a shot of the iPhone screen, and select it all, it return all the selected iPhone screen without the status bar.

Comment: Oh, the latter is not the UIImageView's method, but UIImage category method. First you need to get the UIImageView's snapshot, then crop snapshot with the latter method.

Comment: Man, I tried again you method as you said and now it work 'well' like the one I posted. But it still is inaccurate, it's not 100% perfect, as mine. Can I make a little video to show you ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See the edit. In what coordinate system is your selected rect?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possibile.First you should get the UIImageView's image, using this property:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
```

And NSImage's :

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CGImageRef CGImage;
```

Then you get the cut image:

```
CGImageRef cutImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(yourCGImageRef, CGRectMake(x, y, w, h));
```

If you want again a UIImage you should use this UIImage's method:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)cgImage;
```

**PS:** I don't know how to do it directly, without convert it to CGImageRef, maybe there's a way.

Comment: Show what you've tried, x,y,w,h are just symbolic, what coordinates are you using and what are the view coordinates?

Comment: UIImageView coordinates are: 20,8,280,400. Selected part of the UIImageView coordinates are: 31,255.5,262,142.

Comment: You are going out of bounds, the origin is (20,8) and the other points are the width/height.So for example if you want the lower part of the image you write x=220,y=300, w=60, h=100.If this doen't take the exact coordinates, try to slightly change the rect coordinates and size.Btw I'm not sure that the same of the UIImage.