# How to show in UIImage just a part of image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have `UIImageView` in which I'm showing 50x100 image.

I want to show only a part of image 50x50 (top part)?

How can I do that?

Comment: That's not a duplicate because he's asking something slightly different, but I think it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042260/extract-a-part-of-uiimageview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I might have a solution for you. See if this works. In Interface Builder there is an option about Image content fill properties. You can set it to `top-left`. Follow the image in interface builder -

[image]

After this set the size of `UIImageView` to 50x50 with "clip-subviews" checked...

Comment: This is great solution, just what was I looking for but there is one small problem. Original image is 120x60. :(So I first I need to put to 100x50 and than show just top part 50x50. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: oh cool! glad my solution helped. to answer your comment. I believe you need not do any resizing at all as per the other solution. Just render your image in 50x50 uiimageview set to fill from top. do select clip-subviews for that imageView. that way any part of image outside the 50x50 square will be clipped. This pretty much leaves all the heavy lifting to iOS.

Answer (score 13):

The very simple way to move big image inside *UIImageView* as follows.

Let we have the image of size (100, 400) representing 4 states of some picture one below another. We want to show the 2nd picture having offsetY = 100 in square *UIImageView* of size (100, 100).
The solution is:

```
UIImageView *iView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
CGRect contentFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0.25, 1, 0.25);
iView.layer.contentsRect = contentFrame;
iView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NAME"];
```

Here *contentFrame* is normalized frame relative to real *UIImage* size.
So, "0" means that we start visible part of image from left border,
"0.25" means that we have vertical offset 100,
"1" means that we want to show full width of the image,
and finally, "0.25" means that we want to show only 1/4 part of image in height.

Thus, in local image coordinates we show the following frame

```
CGRect visibleAbsoluteFrame = CGRectMake(0*100, 0.25*400, 1*100, 0.25*400)
or CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100);
```

Comment: One problem with this is that if the number of rows and columns is not a power of 2, then the fractions won't be exact, and the "visibleSbsoluteFrame" won't be at exact integer coordinates

Comment: Do we need to set a contentMode for this?

Answer (score 11):

You can crop the image by using [`CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithImageInRect), which is Quartz primitive working on CGImageRef, so you would have something like:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(originalImage.CGImage, cropRect);
UIImage* outImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:originalImage.scale orientation:originalImage.imageOrientation]]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

When calculation `cropRect`, keep in mind that it should be given in pixels, not in points, i.e.:

```
float scale = originalImage.scale;
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                         originalImage.size.width * scale, originalImage.size.height * 0.5 * scale);
```

where the `0.5` factor accounts for the fact that you want the top half only.

If you do not want to go low-level, you could add your image to a `UIView` as a background color and use the `clipToBounds` CALayer property to make the clipping:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithBackgroundPattern:myImage];
myView.layer.clipToBounds = YES;
```

also, set `myView` bounds accordingly.

Comment: isn't this bad for memory usage? Because i will use that every 10 seconds.

Comment: well, it is not that expensive computationally, I would give it a try and see what happens. In the end, 10 seconds are a lot of time for an operation taking milliseconds to execute...

Comment: Great sergio, sorry but I don't want to mess with memory usage. Srikar is close to solution.