# Make UIImage appear from left to right

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimage

I'm trying to make a cool launch screen but it's a little bit hard. I would like to make my image appear the way this appears:

[what I would like](https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-e9b27ed742.gif)

But for the moment the only animation I succeeded to do is this:

[what I've made](https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-8264bbcbaa.gif)

The image I use is a PNG with transparent border and the yellow drawing.

The code I use to have the animation I have 
( "yellowSide" is actually the name of the outlet from the imageView that hold my image with the yellow drawing):

```
func animation() {
    yellowSide.frame = CGRect(x: yellowSide.frame.origin.x, y: yellowSide.frame.origin.y, width: 0, height: 47)
    yellowSide.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 2.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        var yellowSideFrame = self.yellowSide.frame
        self.yellowSide.frame = CGRect(x: yellowSideFrame.origin.x, y: yellowSideFrame.origin.y, width: 243, height: 47)
        self.yellowSide.alpha = 1

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

As you guess the width / value I enter are the value that I need to have so the image looks the way I want when it's fully appeared.

Comment: This is the wrong approach to achieve what you want to do, `UIBezierPath`   and set Stroke

Comment: Okay I'm gonna search for this see what can help me ! thanks

Comment: @Leo you could achieve what you want with UIImageView by setting the content mode differently. But that is still not the correct way of achieving what you want anyway.

Comment: Thanks Antwan , I've changed the content mode to "top left" and it's exactly what I wanted (even if I guess there is other ways to do it more properly)

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt I got a last little problem if you have a quick solution I would be grateful , with your solution I now got this result :
[here] ( https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-aaeb220768.gif ) 

but the problem is that I'd like to make the red part make like the blue one but from the bottom and I can't find how to do it ..

If you don't have solution don't worry I'll find !

PS: I've already tried all the content mode

Comment: @Leo My solution simply doesn't suffice, give this a try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19084201/257116

Comment: @Leo It is like I said, you most likely don't want to be using images in the first place, but if you are really stoked on doing it... that is how you do it.

Comment: Your links currently are not working, but if if I understand the context correctly then you are trying to move the image offscreen to a position on screen while fading it in? If so then you don't need to touch the width, just start by setting the x position of the image view to -imageView.frame.width and then in your animation block update the x position to where you want it to end at on screen.

Comment: check  my answer below ,,,,,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are changing the frame but you are not clipping  out  of frame image . you need to do like below .

```
 // in ViewDidLoad method
  yellowSide.clipsToBounds=true

func animation() {
     yellowSide.frame = CGRect(x: yellowSide.frame.origin.x, y: yellowSide.frame.origin.y, width: 0, height: 47)
     yellowSide.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 2.0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {

                var yellowSideFrame = self.yellowSide.frame
                self.yellowSide.frame = CGRect(x: yellowSideFrame.origin.x, y: yellowSideFrame.origin.y, width: 243, height: 47)
                self.yellowSide.alpha = 1

            }, completion: nil)

}
```